# Where to put my custom Html Helpers?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, html-helper

Where to put the helper class in the project folder hierarchy ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I would suggest creating a seperate class library so that you can reuse your helpers in other projects as well.

Answer (score 6):

I usually just create a Common or Helpers subdirectory as a place to put these kind of things.