# User Profile property value set as Selected DDL value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I've made a `Profile Model` that stores certain property values. Such as firstName, lastName... etc... Among others `state` is one of them.

Now problem occurred when I've replaced `TextBox` with `DropDownList` for `State` property.
This is the way I've made my `Edit` method in `ProfileController`.

When opened app will populate if any existing values. First issue, how to get selected value from the dropdown, so i can pass it into `Profile` property like I did in this method.

```
public ActionResult Edit(string username)
{
    ViewBag.StateID = new SelectList(db.States, "StateID", "StateName");
    ProfileBase _userProfile = ProfileBase.Create(username);
    ProfileModel _profile = new ProfileModel();
    System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["_userName"] = username;

    if (_userProfile.LastUpdatedDate > DateTime.MinValue)
    {
        _profile.FirstName = Convert.ToString(_userProfile.GetPropertyValue("FirstName"));
        _profile.LastName = Convert.ToString(_userProfile.GetPropertyValue("LastName"));
        _profile.Address = Convert.ToString(_userProfile.GetPropertyValue("Address"));
        _profile.City = Convert.ToString(_userProfile.GetPropertyValue("City"));
        _profile.State = Convert.ToString(_userProfile.GetPropertyValue("State"));
        _profile.Zip = Convert.ToString(_userProfile.GetPropertyValue("Zip"));
    }
    return View(_profile);
}
```

This worked fine when `State` was a string passed in `TextBox`, and then saved with `Edit` post method.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(ProfileModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
        ProfileBase profile = ProfileBase.Create(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["_userName"].ToString(), true);

        if (profile != null)
        {
            profile.SetPropertyValue("FirstName", model.FirstName);
            profile.SetPropertyValue("LastName", model.LastName);
            profile.SetPropertyValue("Address", model.Address);
            profile.SetPropertyValue("City", model.City);
            profile.SetPropertyValue("State", model.State);
            profile.SetPropertyValue("Zip", model.Zip);

            profile.Save();
        }
        else
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Error writing to Profile");
        }
    }
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

This is how I created dropdown for `State`.

Model:

```
public class State
{
    public int StateID { get; set; }
    public string StateName { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<RegisterModel> RegModel { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<ProfileModel> Profiles { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
ViewBag.StateID = new SelectList(db.States, "StateID", "StateName");
```

View:

```
@Html.DropDownList("StateID", (SelectList)ViewBag.StateID, new { @class = "dropdown" })
```

I've tried several things. No luck so far. What am I missing?!

Comment: Try looking here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5052752/adding-your-own-htmlhelper-in-asp-net-mvc-3

Comment: Did you try this? `@Html.DropDownList("StateID", String.Empty)`

Comment: OK for the first suggestion, that will not do since I use `Model` to populate my Dropdown, also my dropdown is working so that wasn't the question at all.
As for second, it throws some error, but that would only give me bit different output on dropdown, which also wasn't my question.
Thanks both for taking your time advising.