# Read content from DOM element with KnockoutJS

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

### The goal

Read content from DOM element with KnockoutJS.

### The problem

I have a list of products in my HTML. The code is something like this:

```
<li>
    <div class="introduction">
        <h3>@Model["ProductName"]</h3>
    </div>
    <form data-bind="submit: addToSummary">
        <input type="number" 
               placeholder="How much @Model["ProductName"] do you want?" />
        <button>Add product</button>
    </form>
</li>
```

When I click on `<button>Add Product</button>`, I want to send to KnockoutJS the text inside `<h3></h3>` of the element that was submitted.

The file to work with KnockoutJS is *external* and *independent* of HTML. It name is `summary.js` and the code is below:

```
function ProductReservation(id, name, unity, quantity) {
    var self = this;

    self.id = id;
    self.name = name;
    self.unity = unity;
    self.quantity = quantity;
}

function SummaryViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    self.products = ko.observableArray([
        new ProductReservation(1, "Testing", "kgs", 1)
    ]);

    self.addToSummary = function () {
        // Do Something
    }
}
```

### What I'm thinking about

**HTML:**

```
<li>
    <div class="introduction">
        <h3 data-bind="text: productName">@Model["ProductName"]</h3>
    </div>
    [...]
</li>
```

**JS:**

```
productName = ko.observable("text: productName");
```

But, of course, no success — this is not the correct context or syntax, was just to illustrate.

So I ask: what I need to do?

Comment: Why not `ko.observable("@(Model["ProductName"])");`?

Comment: Hello, @nemesv. Thanks about your entry. The problem is: I'm working with an external JS file and it does not have access to `@(Model["ProductName"])`. =(

Comment: If you're using jQuery you could select the element with jQuery and grab the value that way.

Comment: @AndrewWhitaker I had thought about it, but believed that KnockoutJS had something to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're binding `addToSummary` via the `submit` binding. By default KO sends the form element to submit-bound functions.

So `addToSummary` should have a parameter -

```
self.addToSummary = function (formElement) {
    // Do Something
}
```

You can pass additional parameters to this function (as described in KO's [click binding documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/click-binding.html) under 'Note 2'), or you could just add a hidden field to your form element and pull it from there.

```
<li>
    <div class="introduction">
        <h3>@Model["ProductName"]</h3>
    </div>
    <form data-bind="submit: addToSummary">
        <input type="number" name="quantity" 
               placeholder="How much @Model["ProductName"] do you want?" />
        <input type="hidden" name="productName" value="@Model["ProductName"]" />
        <button>Add product</button>
    </form>
</li>
```

Then in your knockout code you could use jQuery to process the form element to pull out the data -

```
self.addToSummary = function (formElement) {
    var productName = $(formElement).children('[name="productName"]')[0].val();
    var quantity= $(formElement).children('[name="quantity"]')[0].val();
    // ...
    self.products.push(new ProductReservation(?, productName, ?, quantity));
}
```

Comment: Thats exactly what I wanted! Thanks, @Nate! +1

Answer (score 1):

One strategy that has worked well in my experience is to [implement a `toJSON` extension method](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/10/01/tip-trick-building-a-tojson-extension-method-using-net-3-5.aspx) that serializes your model (if you use a library like JSON.NET you can have a lot of control over what gets serialized and what does not).

Inside of the view where you initialize KnockoutJS, you could serialize your model and pass it into the  KnockoutJS ViewModel you're creating (assuming :

**Main view:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var viewModel = new MyViewModel(@Model.ToJSON());
</script>
```

**ViewModel:**

```
function MyViewModel(options) {
    this.productName = ko.observable(options.ProductName);
}
```

Comment: Hi, @AndrewWhitaker. Thanks about your answer. I have implemented the `toJSON` extension method but in my view (Razor) the `.ToJSON()` method doesn't appear. I already have compiled the code. Any idea?

Comment: You might have to add a reference to your namespace in your web.config. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5052752/497356) for more information. Does that help?