# What is the best practice for transforming a model property in the view?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

Using MVC5, what is the best practice for transforming a model property into a view?

For example, I have a;

```
class Person
{
    DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
}
```

And I'd like to display this property as `Age` (i.e; determine number of years between now and `DateOfBirth`). I *could* just put an extra property on the `Person` type, but wondering if there's a better way to consolidate this code into a single function I can invoke from multiple views as necessary?

Comment: Assuming you didn't want to add some sort of adapter or extension method on DateTime, an HtmlHelper extension would be relatively easy to write.

Comment: If I used a DateTime extension, which is a good idea, how do I invoke that from the view?

Comment: here's a good reference if you want to go the extension route, including how to use it in the view http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5052752/adding-your-own-htmlhelper-in-asp-net-mvc-3

Comment: If you namespace the extension class to the base project namespace or register the extension namespace in your web.config, you use it just like a normal DateTime object: `@DateTime.ToAge()`