# How to pass value to @helper from select list?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, localization

Kinda stupid question, but how do i change the language of my site, i have a function that uses cookies and i just want to call it. like this:

```
    @helper selected(string c, string culture)
{
    if (c == culture)
    {
        @:checked="checked"
    }
}
```

and now i have a

```
    <select>
     <option>English</option>
     <option>German</option>
</select>
```

how do i pass the value to string c from this list?

Comment: What is that function? jquery ? The select list is bound to model or hardcoded? Share some more code.

Comment: Its my custom Helper, it works fine when i use a radio button, but on my select list it doesn't

Comment: share the code for the helper. I'm not able to figure out how this is being called.

Comment: ehm, thats the whole code for the helper

`<html lang="hu">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>BetX Online</title>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="~/Scripts/Layout/ShowLogin.js"></script>
        <script src="~/Scripts/Layout/test.js"></script>
      
       
    </head>
@helper selected(string c, string culture)
{
    if (c == culture)
    {
        @:selected = "selected"
    }
}
`

Comment: and i called it like this: <option id="hu" value="hu" @selected("en", culture)>English</option>

Comment: depending on if it is true or false a new cookie is generated that cointains the id of the language. By the ID of the language it displays it on the page

Comment: Try calling the function from select instead of from options.

This might help you http://stackoverflow.com/a/5052790/1991504

Comment: @NikiteshKolpe THanks! this is something that is really usefull