# Call a C# Method (output string) in ASP.NET for html src statement

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net, razor

I have created some C# Methods and I want to use it as reference for my ASP.NET project.

The method give me a string as output. A example for a string:
"C:/tracks/audio1.mp3"

Now I try to use my Method "GetTrackPath()" for my html audio tag.
Simple -> I want the method output in my

How I can realize it?

**ADD CODE**

```
<audio id="a1" preload="auto" controls>
   <source src="GetTrackPath()">
<audio>
```

Now I want to put the string into the html src tag.

Comment: I don't understand very well what is the problem, can you provide some code and improve the explanation?

Comment: You need to look at creating your own [HTML Helper](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5052752/adding-your-own-htmlhelper-in-asp-net-mvc-3)

Comment: @JackMorton I hope its more logical now.

Comment: Is it Asp.Net MVC or Webforms ?

Comment: @Fabjan It is ASP.NET MVC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a viewmodel and use it in View :

```
namespace MyProject.MyNameSpace

public class AudioTrackVM
{
   public string Id { get; set; }
   public string Preload { get; set; }
   public string Src { get; set; }
}
```

In controller you can add this :

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
   var model = new List<AudioTrackVM>()  // this is stub, get data from data source instead
   {
      new AudioTrackVM() { Id = "a1", Preload = "auto", Src = @"C:/tracks/audio1.mp3" },
      new AudioTrackVM() { Id = "a2", Preload = "auto", Src = @"C:/tracks/audio2.mp3" }
   };
   return View(model);
}
```

Now it is time to use this Viewmodel :

```
@model List<MyProject.MyNameSpace.AudioTrackVM>

@foreach(var audio in Model)
{
   <audio id="@audio.Id" preload="@audio.Preload" controls>
      <source src="@audio.Src">
   <audio>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use code tag

write this in you aspx

```
<audio id="a1" preload="auto" controls>
   <source src="GetTrackPath()">
<audio>
```

write this method in your aspx.cs

```
public string GetTrackPath()
{
    return @"C:/tracks/audio1.mp3";
}
```